# How don't create gem executables when using bundle in a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, bin

I ran this command in my rails project:

```
bundle --binstubs
```

This created a `bin/` directory and generated all of the executables for the gems in my Gemfile.
But I don't need them. Every time I run `bundle install`, it will generate all of that executables.

How can ignore them when I run `bundle install`?

Comment: Checkout the documentation for `bundle`, you can specify the directory you put them in with `bundle --binstubs[=<directory>]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--binstubs` is one of Bundler's ["remembered options"](http://bundler.io/man/bundle-install.1.html#REMEMBERED-OPTIONS), which means as soon as you use it once, it saves that value to a local config file (`.bundle/config`, relative to your Gemfile's location). You can always open up that file and edit it yourself, or you can run:

```
bundle install --no-binstubs
```

And bundler should remember instead to *not* install binstubs in the future. Now, if the above doesn't work on your version of bundler, you may need to run:

```
bundle config --delete bin
```